# ggplot2 grouping lines on geom_line

Tags: r, grouping

I am having some issues when trying to group lines into a single plot.

My data has the following structure:

[image]

I would like to plot the data grouping by 'run', but when I run the following code, I get wrong results:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = epoch, y = accuracy, col = model)) + 
  geom_line(aes(lty = run)) +
  geom_smooth(se = FALSE)
```

[image]

However, if I change 'group' to 'lty', I get the 'right' results.

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Could you provide some usable data and full script? I cannot see the group option. However it seems you're feeding the plot with the not aggregate data, but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: It's always important to provide sample data in a copy&paste-able format. Please review how to provide a [minimal reproducible example/attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). You should edit your post to include the output of `dput` based on (part of) your data. Screenshots are not helpful.